# SSIS Send Email Time out Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis-2008

I am sending one 15 MB file via Send Email Task in SSIS. The task ran fine until today where the Send email task threw an error saying "The operation has time out". I did some googling and found out that we can use Script Task to forcefully include threading for 15 seconds. I am not sure how and where to put the script task.

Help requested.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the link you found that recommends this solution?

Comment: It seems a SMTP settings related issue. Have you got admin rights on STMP server or can you speak with some network guy in order to get those settings? Alternatively, you can try to split the attachment in multiple zip files in order to stay under 15MB (which seems to be your SMTP cap size).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24020880/ssis-send-mail-task-error-an-error-occurred-with-the-following-error-message This is the link @TabAlleman

Comment: Any inputs would be helpful here

Comment: As the answer in that link suggests, did you find and change the timeout setting in the SMTP Connection properties?

Comment: No I didn't find any such settings in SMTP. Hence I was looking for an answer from SO community.